# How do I grant an app access to its own api

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Given the following terraform script, how can I grant the `app_registration` permission to the API it defines?

I've tried adding a `required_resource_access` section but I cannot set `resource_app_id` to the id of my app because it gives a circular reference error.

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}

resource "random_uuid" "app_scope_id" {}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "msgraph" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph
  use_existing   = true
}

resource "azuread_application" "app_registration" {
  display_name     = "My app name"
  identifier_uris  = ["api://${var.environment}productname"]
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled          = true
    # requested_access_token_version = 2

    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allow the application to access a user's name and email address."
      admin_consent_display_name = "Access user name and email address"
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = random_uuid.app_scope_id.result
      type                       = "User"
      user_consent_description   = "Allow the application to access your name and email address."
      user_consent_display_name  = "Access your name and email address"
      value                      = "access_as_user"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph // "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

    resource_access {
      id   =  azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.Read"] // "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d" 
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["email"] // "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e"
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["openid"] // "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0"
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url  = "https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net"
    logout_url    = "https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net/logout"
    redirect_uris = ["https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net//authentication/login-callback"]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}
```

The steps in Azure would be

1. Go to portal.azure.com
2. Switch to the directory where your app is
3. Select "Azure Active Directory" from the burger menu at the top left of the page
4. Click "App registrations"
5. Click the application
6. Click "API permissions"
7. Click "Add a permission"
8. Select "My APIs" tab
9. Click your app in the list
10. Tick the permission "access_as_user"
11. Click "Add permissions"

I would also like to set `identifier_uris` to the apps UUID, but that doesn't seem possible either.

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do that? Normally you would want other users to have access to the app's APIs.

Comment: My client cannot obtain a active directory token giving permission to use my app without it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around I can employ.

The first time the script is executed for a new environment, it must be run twice. Once to create everything, and a second time to add the permissions.

Terraform doesn't have a conditional block of code so we can't optionally include a block, but we can use a ternary statement to make a local variable an empty array or an array with a single element, and then use `for_each`

First, add a variable

```
variable "update_roles" {
  type = string
}
```

Next, define a data-source to retrieve the existing `application_id`, but only if the parameters say we should (i.e. it is the 2nd+ execution of the script).

```
data "azuread_application" "app_registration" {
  display_name = local.app_display_name
  count        = var.update_roles == "y" ? 1 : 0
}
```

Finally, use a `dynamic` block with a `for_each` that will iterate over 1 element (if the 2nd+ execution of the script) or over an empty array (i.e. not execute).

```
  dynamic "required_resource_access" {
    for_each = var.update_roles == "y" ? [1] : [] 
    content {
      resource_app_id = data.azuread_application.app_registration[0].application_id

      resource_access {
        id   =  random_uuid.app_scope_id.result
        type = "Scope"
      }
    }
  }
```

First time you run your script

```
terraform apply --var update_roles=n
```

All subsequent runs

```
terraform apply --var update_roles=y
```

If anyone can give an answer that doesn't require at least two executions for a new environment, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: We implemented the same solution. It is not the best, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you used, adding the `required_resource_access` block to the `azuread_application` resource grants the **"app registration permission"** to the API it defines. You can specify the `resource_app_id` as the `application id` of the `azuread_service_principal` resource that represents the API in this block.

***So, I've given resource app id as:***

```bash
 resource_app_id = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.application_id
```

***I modified your script as below and it registered an app successfully with the required API permissions.***

***main.tf:***

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}

resource "random_uuid" "app_scope_id" {}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "msgraph" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph
  use_existing   = true
}
resource "azuread_application" "app_registration" {
  display_name     = "My app name"
  identifier_uris  = ["api://${var.environment}productname"]
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled          = true
    # requested_access_token_version = 2

    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allow the application to access a user's name and email address."
      admin_consent_display_name = "Access user name and email address"
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = random_uuid.app_scope_id.result
      type                       = "User"
      user_consent_description   = "Allow the application to access your name and email address."
      user_consent_display_name  = "Access your name and email address"
      value                      = "access_as_user"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.application_id

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.Read"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["email"]
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["openid"]
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url  = "https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net"
    logout_url    = "https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net/logout"
    redirect_uris = ["https://${var.environment}productname.azurewebsites.net//authentication/login-callback"]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}
```

`var.tf`:

```bash
variable "environment"{}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init`:

[image]

***Validated the configuration*** using  `terraform validate`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

***Deployment succeeded and got the expected output:***

[image]

***Note:*** Regarding `random_uuid`,  it is not possible to set the `identifier_uris` to the `app's UUID` directly in Terraform. However, you can generate a UUID with the  [`random_uuid`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/uuid) resource and use it in the `identifier_uris` list.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, unfortunately it's not what I meant. My scriptwas correctly adding the MSGraph permissions. What I need is the permission granted to the API it exposes. I will update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: It is not possible in terraform as of now. @PeterMorris